# Search javax mail and return the found word

Tags: regex, search, jakarta-mail

I having trouble implementing this into my program. I'm not sure what to do..

At the moment I have this:

```
String content = message.getContent().toString();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:Feb)"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher(content); 
if (m.matches())
{   
    System.out.print(m.group(1));  
}
else
{
    System.out.print("no matches");  
}
System.out.println(content); //this will just print all the content.
```

However this doesn't return anything.. I've tried other methods of regex to no avail. In the console I can see the whole mail printed. The fourth line contains a word which I want to grab and use somewhere else. It could be any month Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul, etc... I want my code to tell me which one it is.

Anyone know how to do this? (ps. my code is probably completely wrong!) Maybe I could use the javax.search.BodyTerm but that seems to just return true/false..

An example email:

> Hello,
>   la la la la la
>   I want the month below.
>   Friday, Mar 14, 2014
>   good bye.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this line:

```
if (m.matches()) { System.out.print(m.group(1)); }
```

You will need:

```
if (m.find()) { System.out.print(m.group()); }
```

It is because `Matcher#matches()` method return true only if matches complete input.

Also you are not capturing any group so you cannot use `group(1)` just use `group()`.